# How can I make customize use single quote for quotation?

Tags: customize

Is it possible to teach customize to save its variables using single quote `'` instead of `quote`?

Example:

```
…
'(package-archives '(("gnu"   . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
                     ("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/")))
…
```

instead of:

```
…
'(package-archives (quote (("gnu"   . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
                           ("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/"))))
…
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Whether Lisp objects are printed using `'` and `#'` is controlled by `print-quoted`.

See section [Output Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Output-Variables.html) of the Emacs Lisp manual.

So,

```
(advice-add 'custom-save-all :around
            (lambda (orig)
              (let ((print-quoted t))
                (funcall orig))))
```

tells customize to use `'` instead of `(quote ...)` and `#'` instead of `(function ...)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That really rubbed my OCD the right way. :D

Answer (score 1):

If you need compatibility with Emacs older than 24.4 this will do as well:

```
(defadvice custom-save-all (around custom-save-all-around)
  "Use abbreviated quotes for customize."
  (let ((print-quoted t))
    ad-do-it))
```

[Reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Porting-old-advices.html#Porting-old-advices)